# error Attempted to read or write protected memory, where to look?

Tags: c#, memory, directinput

I'm getting the following error with unmanaged code in .net 2.0 using the dx 2006 managed references (I can not find anything newer that has a managed code folder).

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I was wondering how to figure out what memory I may have corrupted as this is pretty much a one for one from example code.  Though to be sure here is the code that fails.

```
Effect effect;
        EffectObject eo = null; 
        public void doFFBAPI(Device joystick)
        {
            // Query all suported ForceFeedback effects
            var allEffects = joystick.GetEffects( EffectType.All );

            //Configure axes
            int[] axis = null;
            foreach (DeviceObjectInstance doi in joystick.Objects)
            {

                //Set axes ranges.
                if ((doi.ObjectId & (int)DeviceObjectTypeFlags.Axis) != 0)
                {
                    joystick.Properties.SetRange(
                    ParameterHow.ById,
                    doi.ObjectId,
                    new InputRange(-5000, 5000));
                }

                int[] temp;

                //  Get info about first two FF axii on the device
                if ( ( doi.Flags & (int)ObjectInstanceFlags.Actuator ) != 0 )
                {
                    if ( axis != null )
                    {
                        temp = new int[axis.Length + 1];
                        axis.CopyTo( temp, 0 );
                        axis = temp;
                    }
                        else
                    {
                        axis = new int[1];
                    }

                    // Store the offset of each axis.
                    axis[axis.Length - 1] = doi.Offset;
                    if ( axis.Length == 2 )
                    {
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }


            foreach (EffectInformation ei in joystick.GetEffects(EffectType.CustomForce))
            {
                // Fill in some generic values for the effect.
                effect = new Effect();
                effect.SetDirection(new int[axis.Length]);
                effect.SetAxes(new int[1]); //.SetAxes(new int[axis.Length]); ->may cause invaild range error?
                effect.ConditionStruct = new Condition[axis.Length];

                effect.EffectType = EffectType.CustomForce;
                effect.ConditionStruct = new Condition[axis.Length];
                effect.Duration = (int)DI.Infinite;
                effect.Constant = new ConstantForce();
                effect.Constant.Magnitude = 100;
                effect.Gain = 10000;
                effect.SamplePeriod = 0;
                effect.TriggerButton = (int)Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Button.NoTrigger;
                effect.TriggerRepeatInterval = (int)DI.Infinite;
                effect.Flags = EffectFlags.ObjectOffsets | EffectFlags.Cartesian;
                effect.UsesEnvelope = false;

                Periodic p = new Periodic();
                p.Magnitude = 10;
                p.Offset = 10;
            p.Period = 10;
            p.Phase = 10;
            effect.Periodic = p;

            int[] forces;
            forces = new int[24];
            forces[0] = 79;
            forces[1] = 1;
            forces[2] =  1;
            forces[3] =  1;
            forces[4] =  1;
            forces[5] =  1;
            forces[6] =  1;
            forces[7] =  1;
            forces[8] =  1;
            forces[9] =  1;
            forces[10] = 1;
            forces[11] = 1;
            forces[12] = 1;
            forces[13] = 1;
            forces[14] = 1;
            forces[15] = 1;
            forces[16] = 1;
            forces[17] = 1;
            forces[18] = 1;
            forces[19] = 1;
            forces[20] = 1;
            forces[21] = 1;
            forces[22] = 1;
            forces[23] = 1;

            CustomForce CF = new CustomForce();
            CF.Channels = 2;
            CF.Samples = 12;
            CF.SamplePeriod = 1000;
            CF.SetForceData(forces);

            effect.CustomStruct = CF;

            // Create the effect, using the passed in guid.
            eo = new EffectObject(ei.EffectGuid, effect, joystick);
            //eo.SetParameters(effect, EffectParameterFlags.Start); 

        }
    }
```

I'm not sure any other code would be relevant but ill post it if needed. If I change my effect object constructor to use no effect (eo = new EffectObject(ei.EffectGuid, joystick);) it does so without the error but  when adding the effect via SetParameters the error is thrown. From what I have read on this error the hard part is tracking down the DLL that is causing the error but in this case I know it is directinput. So from here what can I do to figure out the memory leak or corruption?

Not sure a call stack would help in this case but here it is:

```
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll!Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.EffectObject.InternalCreate(System.Guid eff, ref Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Effect die, Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Device dev) + 0xd7 bytes   
    Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll!Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.EffectObject.EffectObject(System.Guid eff, Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Effect die, Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Device dev) + 0x4d bytes 
>   Bliss-BoxAPI.exe!BlissBox.DXinput.doFFBAPI(Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Device joystick) Line 162 + 0xbd bytes C#
    Bliss-BoxAPI.exe!BlissBox.BBapi.Main() Line 28 + 0xd bytes  C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x3a bytes    
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x2b bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x66 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x6f bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes
```

Comment: Also wanted to note:  I need to use direct input because I have a DI hid device that must use customforce (so that puts sharpDX/slimDX out of the picture as they have customforce bugs). Maybe this error is the same issue that I get with  sharpDX/slimDX (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/125605/sharpdx-error-the-parameter-is-incorrect-how-to-debug-from-dx) but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: what is `Effect` and what does `EffectObject` do with it? it sounds like `effect` is GCed after the loop and cleans up some unmanaged resources that `eo` needs. also, why do you create new instance for `eo` in each iteration?

Comment: The loop is for devices, and it creats an effect object for each one. The error occurs on the first match. Effect and EffectObject are part of the DX wrapper. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb321295(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wow I just learned about mdx...

mdx 1.1 has a bug.

mdx 2.0 seems to have fixed the bug but no longer can be used in favor of xna.

xna does not work with non xinput devices, suggests to use 1.1.

And here we have an infinite loop.

So confused by Microsoft's decisions.